# Spelling error in off-topic message?

Tags: bug, status-completed

> - This question does not appear to be about drupal, within the scope defined in the help center.

Shouldn't Drupal be upper case here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site's topic setting used in the off topic description was set to `drupal`. I now changed it to `Drupal`. The settings are *cached*, so the change will *not* be visible immediately. Thanks for reporting it.